# Replace text with my own - jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

This is part of the output dynamically generated by a large page of jQuery. The text inside the spans is generated inside an external script I dont have access to. I want to replace that with my own text.

How could I do that?

```
    <div class="questionDiv">
        <div class="innerQuestionDiv" id="firstQuestion">
            <span class="question">
                THIS IS THE FIRST QUESTION
            </span>
        </div>
     </div>

     <div class="questionDiv">
        <div class="innerQuestionDiv" id="secondQuestion">
            <span class="question">
                THIS IS THE SECOND QUESTION
            </span>
        </div>
     </div>
```

Maybe somthing like this...

```
     //TO REMOVE EXISTING TEXT
     $('#firstQuestion').innerhtml('');
     //AND REPLACE
     $('#firstQuestion').innerhtml('<span class="question">MY QUESTION</span>')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you need to identify *which* parent you're working with. In this example I've chosen the `firstQuestion` div. Then I expanded the selector to target the child `span`, whose class name is "question". Once you have the span element, use jQuery's [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) function to updates its contents (if you're just updating it with new text):

```
$('#firstQuestion .question').text('your new text');
```

If you're going to add HTML content, use [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) instead:

```
$('#firstQuestion .question').html('<strong>your new text</strong>');
```

Alternatively, you can just replace the entire contents of the div as you were attempting in your second code snippet:

```
$('#firstQuestion').html('<span class="question">MY QUESTION</span>');
```

Answer (score 3):

You would just need to preface the ID of your ID with the '#' symbol to denote a match by ID and then you could use the [.html() function](http://api.jquery.com/html/) to handle your replacement :

```
 //Removes the contents of your element
 $("#firstQuestion").html('');

 //Updates the contents
 $("#firstQuestion").html("NEW VALUE");
```

It should be noted that you could use the [.text() function](http://api.jquery.com/text/) as well, however it will not format explicit HTML tags if they are entered.

Comment: Ha! So I almost had it! Cheers for the help, works perfectly now.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('firstQuestion').innerhtml('');  //WRONG and missed # for id selectors
$('#firstQuestion').innerHTML('');  //Correct
```

You can use **`.text()`/`.html()`** in jQuery

```
$('#firstQuestion').html('');
$('#firstQuestion').html('MY QUESTION');
```

Answer (score -1):

Your [Jquery selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) is Invalid

```
   $('#firstQuestion').html('<span class="question">MY QUESTION</span>');
```

You should either use `#` (for ID's)  or `.`  for `class`.

Comment: firstQuestion is an id